# Update Record in Sqlite Window Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my database I have table named question1, with the initial default status assigned = 0, then every time I want to update I want the status = 1, I use the command

```
await conn.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE question1 SET Status = '1' WHERE id =" + ques1.id);
```

but it is not working. Who knows what is wrong here? Here's the code to read the data and update the table......

```
public async Task<question1> get_data_question1()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Database");
    var query = conn.Table<question1>().Where(x => x.Status == 0);
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();
    question1 ques1 = new question1();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        ques1.id = item.id;
        ques1.Status = item.Status;
    }
    // Update
    await conn.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE question1 SET Status = '1' WHERE id =" + ques1.id);
    return ques1;
}
```

Comment: What value does ques1.id have?  Is there a Column name id in your table? There's a good w3shools reference on sql commands: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: table question of my have 2 column id and status. ques1.id is value id of a record in database

Comment: I mean put a break point before the conn.ExecuteAsync, what is the debug value of ques1.id?

Comment: Debug value of ques1.id by id in database record.

Comment: I didn't think the language barrier would be that great.... What exactly is the value of ques1.id?  Is it 1, or 2, or 3 or 4 .... or it a string/char "1", or "2", or "33", or '1', or '2', or '3'.  Don't assume anything, just answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set up your simple database.

It will create 3 entries with all Status = 0.

Put a break point at the line where I said so in the code;

You will see after that query all 0 values has been updated to 1.

```
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Question
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
} 

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string dbPath = "";
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");                        

        CreateDBTable();
        InsertDB();         // only call this once (comment it out the next time you deploy)
        UpdateDB();

    }
}

// from the MSDN example
private async Task<bool> FileExists(string fileName)
{
    var result = false;
    try
    {
        var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        result = true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return result;
}

public void CreateDBTable()
{
    if (!FileExists("db.sqlite").Result)
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<Question>();
        }
    } 
}

public void UpdateDB()
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        var existing = db.Query<Question>("SELECT * FROM Question WHERE Status = 0");
        if (existing != null)
        {
            foreach(Question q in existing)
            {
                db.Execute("UPDATE Question SET Status = 1 WHERE Id = ?", q.Id);
            }
        }


        // query again to see if has changed
        existing.Clear();

        existing = db.Query<Question>("SELECT * FROM Question WHERE Status = 1");
        if (existing != null)
        {
            int breakpoint_here = 1;
        }

    } 
}

private void InsertDB()
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            db.Insert(new Question() { Status = 0 });
            db.Insert(new Question() { Status = 0 });
            db.Insert(new Question() { Status = 0 });
        });
    }
}
```